# How can I copy/duplicate a file to another directory using SFTP?

Tags: sftp

I have created a directory within an SFTP location and I want to move a file from one SFTP directory to another directory but `cp` command is not supported there.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 13):

The core SFTP protocol does not support duplicating a remote file.

There's draft of [`copy-file` extension to the protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00). But that's supported by only few SFTP servers ([ProFTPD `mod_sftp`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html) and Bitvise SFTP server for example) and few SFTP clients ([WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_move_duplicate) for example).

The most widespread SFTP server, the OpenSSH supports related `copy-data` only in very recent [version 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0). Its `sftp` client has now [`cp`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#cp)/[`copy`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#copy) command.

---

Alternatives:

- If you have SSH/terminal access into the server, use the [shell `cp` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html).
- If your SFTP server supports the `copy-file` extension, use an SFTP client that supports it too.
- Otherwise, your only option is to download the file to a local temporary location and upload its copy back to a different/target remote directory.
  Some SFTP clients can do this for you even transparently in one go (e.g. in WinSCP, see *Duplicate via local temporary copy* option on [Duplicate dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_duplicate)).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 1):

You can clone remote directories using WinSCP in command line mode (`winscp /console`). Let's imagine you have a the following structure on the remote SFTP server:

```
theDestinationDirectory/
  |-file1.txt
  |-file2.txt
```

You can copy this remote directory using the following script (in WinSCP console):

```
open sftp://myUsername:myPassword@myftp.mydomain.com
mkdir theDestinationDirectory
call cp theSourceDirectory/* theDestinationDirectory/ -r
```

Then you can check that your copy has been done properly (in the WinSCP console):

```
ls theDestinationDirectory

drwxr-sr-x   2 uid12345 gid12345        37 Jul 29 23:50:24 2016 .
drwxr-sr-x   6 uid12345 gid12345        75 Jul 29 23:50:11 2016 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 uid12345 gid12345     29670 Jul 29 23:50:24 2016 file1.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 uid12345 gid12345     12432 Jul 29 23:50:24 2016 file2.txt
```

Note that as Martin Prikryl wrote, this may not be supported by all SFTP servers... (at least it's supported by mine)

Comment: Few notes: You confuse FTP and SFTP. You are connecting to an SFTP server, not FTP. And you are actually not using the SFTP for the copy. You are invoking a shell command `cp` for the copy (using the [WinSCP command `call`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_call)). So actually your solution has nothing to do with SFTP (nor FTP) - In my answer this apporach is covered by the *"If you have SSH/terminal access into the server, use shell `cp` command."*

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : you're right, I was using the FTP term in a confusing way and edited the answer accordingly. BTW thanks for WinSCP, that's a great tool.